# Magento 2 - Fotorama

Tags: jquery, slider, magento2, fotorama

I have a problem with the ProductSlider on the Productdetail Page. I dont know how to set the Container width & heights.

I found some configuration for the Fotorama Plugin but there is nothing about width and height.

My Productimages have another dimensions.

`<div class="fotorama__stage" style="width: 581px; height: 581px; line-height: 581px;">`

that are the dimensions from the Plugin.

My image dimensions are `530px x 350px`, so there is too much white-space (top/bottom).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You have to edit the following file: `app/design/vendor/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

Here you can add your options

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            "magnifierOpts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMagnifier(); ?>,
            "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
            "options": {
                "maxheight": "700", // Add your value here
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Overwrite `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml`

I have the following, for example: `app\design\frontend\[CustomTheme]\default\etc\view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>420</height>
            </image>

            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>420</height>
            </image>

            <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>420</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

This will cause the `fotorama__stage` to be smaller - it adjusts based on the image size.

Comment: Above code is changing the size of the image but not for the div <div class="fotorama__stage" style="width: 581px; height: 581px; line-height: 581px;">

Comment: Make sure you flush all cache.  I'm pretty sure the div did shrink on the project I was working on, as that was my intent.  I will have to try to remember what project this was and see for sure, but I would start by ensuring all of your cache is flushed.

Comment: Yes, I have all the cache and cleared pub directory as well.

Comment: Hey - I did check this and it did change the size of the container as well.  I'm not sure if extra CSS was needed for that.  Unfortunately I no longer work with Magento, so I can't look back and give you more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from Florin Marin worked for me but without changing width of fotorama, so I was digging more and for me - best result was adding this to my less theme file _theme.less

```
        .page-layout-2columns-right .product.media {
                width: 20%
}
        .page-layout-2columns-right .product-info-main {
                width: 78%;
}
```

I change also size of images in app/design/frontend/[Custom_Vendor]/[CustomTheme]\etc\view.xml same like adpro in his answer.

```
 <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>150</width>
                <height>150</height>
            </image>

            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>150</width>
                <height>150</height>
            </image>

            <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
                <width>150</width>
                <height>150</height>
            </image>
        </images>
```

in developer mode delete pub/static/frontend/*
and after changes in xml file resize images:
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your LESS/CSS file and clear the cache.

```
.product .fotorama__stage__frame .fotorama__img {
   top: 0 !important;
   transform: none !important;
   -webkit-transform: none !important;
   position: static;
   margin-top: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show how it is done properly, but keep in mind that this does not support all options, so you also have to extend the block class and add support for the missing options by yourself if you need to use them!

The config is saved in

**theme-frontend-blank/etc/view.xml**:

```
...
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">

    <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
        <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
        ...
```

Copy the **view.xml** into your own theme and overwrite that part.

You should change these variables instead.

You can find all possible options in the fotorama [documentation](https://fotorama.io/docs/4/options/).

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me, hope it will help others as well.

Place this code just after your code in gallery.phtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui'
    ],
    function(
        $
    ) {
        $(window).load(function(){
            console.log("readyyy");
            $(".fotorama__stage").height($(".fotorama__img").height());

            $( window ).resize(function() {
                console.log("resize");
              $(".fotorama__stage").height($(".fotorama__img").height());
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these solutions but didn't work. I was able to solve this by adding the below CSS

```
.fotorama__stage {
    max-height: 80%;
}
```